# VAE reconstruction loss does not get calculated right

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I wanted to implement a variational autoencoder and train it on my texture dataset which consists of colored images of the size 512x512.

For the VAE implementation, I took the Keras-VAE from https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/ as an example and changed the layer-structure. After training, I looked at some reconstruction images and they were really blurry. I then looked at how the reconstruction loss was calculated and found it in this piece of the code:

```
def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(data)
            reconstruction = decoder(z)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction)
            )
            reconstruction_loss *= 28 * 28
            kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var)
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss)
            kl_loss *= -0.5
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
```

Since the example VAE is used on the mnist-dataset (image size is 28x28) I intuitively thought that I had to change the reconstruction loss to

```
reconstruction loss *= 512*512  #since my images are of the size 512x512
```

When I train the VAE now the total_loss often rockets to numbers like 904815524.6657 in the first training epoch even though the reconstruction loss in the same first epoch is around 15000 and also the average total_loss is around 15000. After a while, the total_loss and kl_loss sometimes also display nan after a while of training. Also, the reconstructed images with the reconstruction_loss * = 28 * 28 seemed better than with 512*512...

Did I implement the loss the right way and how can I solve this problem with the absurdly high total_loss?

Edit:

Model summary for encoder and decoder:

`````
Model: "encoder"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 512, 512, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 256, 256, 64) 1792        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)         (None, 256, 256, 64) 0           conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 256, 256, 64) 256         activation[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 128, 128, 64) 36928       batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 128, 128, 64) 256         activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 64, 64, 128)  73856       batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 64, 64, 128)  512         activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 524288)       0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 512)          268435968   flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_mean (Dense)                  (None, 512)          262656      dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
z_log_var (Dense)               (None, 512)          262656      dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sampling (Sampling)             (None, 512)          0           z_mean[0][0]                     
                                                                 z_log_var[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 269,074,880
Trainable params: 269,074,368
Non-trainable params: 512
__________________________________________________________________________________________________````

Model: "decoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 512)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 524288)            268959744 
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 64, 64, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_4 (Conv2DTr (None, 128, 128, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (Batch (None, 128, 128, 128)     512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DTr (None, 256, 256, 64)      73792     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (Batch (None, 256, 256, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_6 (Conv2DTr (None, 512, 512, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (Batch (None, 512, 512, 64)      256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_7 (Conv2DTr (None, 512, 512, 3)       1731      
=================================================================
Total params: 269,220,803
Trainable params: 269,220,291
Non-trainable params: 512
_________________________________________________________________
`````

Comment: I suspect that the blurriness may come from your model design.  Please update your question to provide the encoder and decoder code, or at least the model summary.  There doesn't look like anything is wrong with your loss function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added the model summary to the question. So the loss function with ````reconstruction_loss *= 512*512```` is fine?

Comment: If multiplying by 512*512 is exploding the gradient, then skip it.  Looking at your network I do have some feedback.  The line dense_2 (Dense)(None, 524288) has a large number of parameters.  If instead you change your 3x3 kernel_sizes to 5x5 kernels (with a max 64 features) and add two more conv2d, 2 more conv2d_transpose your number of trainable parameter count will be much less and it will generalize better.  The dense_2 layer is a non-generalizable layer with 1/4 billion weights that all need individual exercise.  Finally, if you can flatten and skip the dense all together, even better.